# np.mean() gives wrong mean?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm getting trouble to calculate the mean value of each column of tow 2d numpy array. Each column of both array are x,y coordinate of an ellipsis. I thus want to calculate the center of these ellipsis to center them. So, i use np.mean() to do so but i get wrong values. If i plot the ellipsis and the centers, the ellipsis are indeed ellipsis-shaped but the points are not (at all) at the centers. So, it is not due to bad ellipsis point.

```
    def acquire(self, qt, it, lapNumber):
        if self.stream is None:
            self.stream = {'qt': qt, 'it': it}
            self.mean   = {'qt': np.zeros(qt.shape), 'it': np.zeros(it.shape)}
        else:
            self.stream['qt'] = np.vstack((self.stream['qt'], qt - self.mean['qt']))
            self.stream['it'] = np.vstack((self.stream['it'], it - self.mean['it']))

        if self.stream['qt'].shape[0] > 950:
            self.mean['qt'] = np.mean(self.stream['qt'], axis=0)
            self.mean['it'] = np.mean(self.stream['it'], axis=0)

            self.stream['qt'] -= self.mean['qt']
            self.stream['it'] -= self.mean['it']

            self.centered = True
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you could reduce this problem to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it while creating a minimum reproducible example. The ellipsis points are actually not uniformly distributed in space. So the mean is not the center and is actually far from the center.